# Issue with background image responsiveness and fit

Tags: css

I am having an issue getting my background image in my header to look right.

Right now, it is set to:

```
.hero {
   background: url(http://wordstream-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/landing_pages/assets/img/e682443e-b4c0-483f-823e-8170fd4b71b2) no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Ive tried many variations of css to get it to work but cant figure it out. I would like the section to show the full image and keep showing it (not cut it off) as the browser shrinks. As of now, it is cutting on the top and bottom of the image until I shrink down and then it shows the whole thing. When I shrink further, it cuts off the sides.

When I switched the bg size to contain, I was left with a bunch of space around the image on small devices. Any help is appreciated.

Link: http://solatube.solabrite.com/premier-dealer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, the aspect ratio of `.hero` needs to match that of the image. You can do this by applying a padding to the element with the percentage amount that represents the image aspect ratio. You can get that percentage by dividing the image height by it's width (500/1280 = 39.0625%).

Add this CSS

```
.hero {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 39.0625%;
}
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use`background-size: cover`, then the image will be scaled until it covers the whole available space.

Maybe try it with `background-size: contain`, then the image will be scaled until it covers either the ***x*** or ***y*** dimension of the available space.

**BUT**: If your image has the same aspect ratio as the area it is trying to cover, neither of this should be a problem though.